# To display the last modified dates for the files in Template::Toolkit file

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I have to display the list of files and last modified dates for the files after uploading functionality.

When we upload the files they will move into a single directory. After that I have to display the list of files with their last modified dates in the "template toolkit" file.

For retrieving the list of files I am using this Perl code

```
my $path = "/sa2/tools/jayaram_delete";

if (chdir($path)) {
    @files = glob "*";
}
else {
    @files = ();
}

print STDERR "FiveJayaram:@files";
$c->stash->{myoptions} = \@files;
```

In the same I have to retrieve the last modified date for the files.

For displaying the files in the `.tt` file:

```
[% FOREACH my IN myoptions%]
<tr class=propertyTableValueColValue><td><div><b>[% my %]</b></div></td></tr>
[% END %]
```

Please help me to display the list of files and the last modified dates in the `.tt` file using Perl.

Comment: Working examples are mostly good start, http://search.cpan.org/~abw/Template-Toolkit-2.24/lib/Template/Tutorial/Web.pod#Generating_Static_Web_Content

Comment: That all looks reasonable at a first glance. What are you having problems with? Getting the timestamps? Displaying your data? Both?

Answer (score 0):

In the first part of your script you should use *opendir* to retrieve the files and *stat* to get the modified date of the files. Like this:

```
opendir my $ls,$path or die $!;
while (my $file = readdir $ls ) {
    next if !-f "$path/$file";

    my @stat = stat("$path/$file");
    push @files, [ $file , localtime($stat[9]) ];
}
closedir $ls;
```

Now you have a list that you must pass to the template. Each item in the list is a reference to a list with the file and mtime. You should pass this list to the template and retrieve it. Check this document about accessing references of lists in TT:

http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_List_References

You also may want to get the mtime in a different format. Run perldoc -f localtime to see examples of how to do it.